# phpMyAdmin connection string on local area network

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm running phpmyadmin with php5 on a debian computer in the basement, and I cannot figure out how to change the connection string. I just get the error message:

> Query failed: Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Here's the code that I modified from what was working when I was using 000webhost as a dev server:

```
<?php
$mysql_host = "192.168.1.138";
$mysql_database = "db_main";
$mysql_user = "username";
$mysql_password = "deadmantellnotales";

$con = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
mysql_select_db($mysql_database);

?>
```

None of the threads I seem to find have a php solution, I keep getting java results in my google searches that clearly say php.

Comment: It's showing you are trying to connect with an incorrect user and no password. Is it possible that is the wrong file that is trying to connect? It would have failed with "user 'username'@'192.168.1.138' using password..."

Comment: I don't understand. It worked on 000webhost. Do I have to change the value for $mysql_host?

Comment: Are you running the script on the same server as the mysql database? If so then use localhost. If not, use it's IP.

Comment: Awesome. Put that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the script on the same server as the mysql database? If so then use localhost. If not, use it's IP.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the error message that you given comes up when you are trying to login with out giving a password  ( that is why you see the message "using password NO" ).

I think,  the script you are editing, is not the script ran when you are trying to run it.  First trace the flow to find out the script responsible for this error message and edit that script.

Hope this helps.